# How to apply a big view style to a notification using Parse library

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform

This library works perfectly, but i have a doubt.

When I send a message to users with more than two lines, users can't see all message in notification area.

But I know that ANDROID can do it

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle. How to do it for notification from `parse.com` ?

Look the images to explain my problem

[Image1 http://gorio.eng.br/parse1.png](http://gorio.eng.br/parse1.png)

[Image2 http://gorio.eng.br/parse2.png](http://gorio.eng.br/parse2.png)

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: i am also facing same problem have you got the solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.gorio);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext()).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Exemplo 1")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gorio)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon1).setContentText("Hello World!");

            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigText.bigText(msg);
            bigText.setBigContentTitle("GORIO Engenharia");
            bigText.setSummaryText("Por: GORIO Engenharia");
            mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
            mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);

            // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back
            // stack for
            // the
            // started Activity.
            // getApplicationContext() ensures that navigating backward from
            // the Activity leads out of
            // your application to the Home screen.
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
                    .create(getApplicationContext());

            // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent
            // itself)
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

            // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the
            // stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 23):

Here's an example using `Notification.BigTextStyle`.

```
    final String someLongText = "fkdljfdldkfj;ldaksjfkladj;flja;lkjdfljadslfjaddfdsfafjdfad" +
            "fdl;akjf;lkdf;lkaj;flkjda;lkfjadljflk;adsjfladjflk;dfjlkdjflakdfjdaffjdlfjdjjj" +
            "adjflkjadlkfjad;lkfjad;sljf;ladkjajlkfjad;lksfjl;akdjf;lkdsajf;lkdjfkadj;flkad" +
            "jf;lkadjfkldas;lkfja;dljf;lkdasjf;lkadjs;lfjas;ldkfj;lkadsjfl;kadljfl;kasdjf;l" +
            "jdlskfjklda;fjadslkfj;sdalkfj;ladjf;lajdl;fkajld;kfjlajfl;adjfl;kajdl;fjadl;kfj;";

    final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
            .bigText(someLongText)
            .setBigContentTitle("Big title")
            .setSummaryText("Big summary"))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Summary")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);

    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, builder.build());
```

[image: Example]

Comment: OK, but my doubt is about using Parse Library. Big Styler of google i saw in google docummentation, but how to integrate it with Parse library ?

Comment: i am also facing same problem have you got the solution?

Comment: The question clearly asks how to do this in parse, not in android's default notification.

Comment: `Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14): android.app.Notification.Builder#setStyle`

Answer (score 6):

This snippet shows how to construct the **Builder object**. It sets the style for the big view to be **big text**, and sets its content to be the reminder message.

```
String msg="This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification  builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder.This is Big style notification builder."

// Constructs the Builder object.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification))
    .setContentText(getString(R.string.ping))
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))

final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(0, builder.build());
```

For more infomation go to:http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html

Comment: OK, but my doubt is about using Parse Library. Big Styler of google i saw in google docummentation, but how to integrate it with Parse library ?

Comment: @Gorio what was that?

Comment: Please, see this site https://parse.com/ . Parse's library work as the same of Google Cloud Messaging and i'd like to use big view to Push Notifications, like your example above..

Comment: @Gorio wait a min i'll try by my self

Comment: @Gorio i am also facing same problem have you got the solution?

Comment: @Gorio where you have posted i can't find ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here I have attached a screenshots, the first screen contents a title of the post and when we click on the down arrow on right side of the app name it leads to the second screenshot which is custom layout for push notification.The following is sample layout that I have designed for mine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#80000000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    tools:text="Test"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:contentDescription="@null"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Method for creating Notification with custom layout,

```
public static void createNotification(String title, String body,String image_url, Context context, int notificationsId, String single_id) {
Intent notificationIntent;

long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(image_url);
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notifystyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
notifystyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, bitmap);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, body);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(notifystyle)
        .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
        .setContentText(body);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SinglePost.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("single_id",single_id);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notificationIntent, 0); 

Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


mNotificationManager.notify(notificationsId, notification);

}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you set

```
String en_alert ,th_alert ,en_title,th_title ,id;
int noti_all, noti_1, noti_2, noti_3, noti_4 = 0, Langage;

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReserveStatusActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

 NotificationManager notificationManager =
      (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(PushActivity.class));
intent.putExtra("message", MESSAGE);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(PushActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
// PendingIntent pendingIntent =
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
// bigStyle.bigText((CharSequence) context);

notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                 .setContentTitle(th_title ) // th_title  >>> String =  th_title   
                 .setContentText(th_alert)   // th_alert>>> String =  th_title
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 //.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_title))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setNumber(++numMessages)
                .build();

notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

notificationManager.notify(1000, notification);
```

Facebook facebook.com/PongLoveWii

Answer (score 1):

```
final String someLongText = "......";

final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
        .bigText(someLongText)
        .setBigContentTitle("Big title")
        .setSummaryText("Big summary"))
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Summary");

final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can build notification with big Text Style 
try this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(id /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method getNotification of your ParsePushBroadcastReceiver subclass and above there is a lot answers telling how to set the big content view on a Notification.