# Android push notification showing text in single line

Tags: android, push-notification

I have search and found solution but that solution is not showing multi line push notification.
My code is below,

```
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id", u_id);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);


    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getNotificationIcon()))
            .setContentText(messageBody).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

How can I show multi line text in push notification?

Comment: see this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079663/how-to-apply-a-big-view-style-to-a-notification-using-parse-library

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, target.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
       Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.youricon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setLargeIcon(image)
            .setContentText("Message")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap).setSummaryText("multiline text"));

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(m/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```